# immutably update array of objects in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability, mutable

I am mutating state here, but I don't want to! All my attempts to not mutate state have come back with syntax errors, so I have turned here.

this is my redux data structure:

```
controls: (array)[
    0:
        id: "e06c5fbf-6d57-4f5b-a601-bfc4ad265def"
        status: 'complete'
        files: []
    1:
        id: "e06c5fbf-6d57-4f5b-a601-bfc4ad265def"
        status: 'complete'
        files: []
    ...
    ]
```

// and my reducer

```
export default function frameworkReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    case RECEIVE_CONTROL_STATUS_UPDATE:
            const index = action.payload.index;
            const newState = {...state};
            newState.controls[index] = { ...state.controls[index], status: action.payload.value };
            return newState
```

Comment: what do you get as result??

Comment: with my current code, it properly edits the desired status property, but it doesn't do it immutably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

// reducer

```
    let index = action.payload.index
    let controls = [...state.controls];
    controls[index] = {...controls[index], status: action.payload.value};
    return {...state, controls}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding and updating particular row/item.

```
           case RECEIVE_CONTROL_STATUS_UPDATE:
            let findItem = state.controls.find(a=>a.index===action.payload.index);
            let filtered = state.controls.filter(a=>a.index!==action.payload.index);
            let updateState = [filtered, findItem];
            return {
              ...state,
              constrols: updatedState
            }
```